# Getting geb.driver.DriverCreationException when I run jenkins automation(Selenium with groovy) job on LINUX computer

Tags: java, python, c#, selenium, jenkins

Getting geb.driver.DriverCreationException when I run jenkins automation(Selenium with groovy) job on LINUX computer.

I am writing Automation script on selenium with Groovy.
Environmnet details are as follow:

```
java version = 1.8.0_261
Gradle = 5.2.1
gebVersion = "2.3.1"
testngVersion = "6.14.3"
seleniumVersion = "3.4.0"
```

**Note:** Same script is working properly with IntelliJ into my local window computer.

As per my knowledge generally we get **geb.driver.DriverCreationException** when there is:

1. chromedriver and chrome browser not installed
2. chromedriver not placed on correct location
3. Version of chromedriver is not compatible with the chrome browser.

I have verified all the above conditions are correct but still I am getting same exception.

Can someone please suggest me what could be the another possible reason to get **geb.driver.DriverCreationException** and how I can resolve this issue?

[image: Console picture_1]

[image: Console picture_2]

** HTML Report error:**

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'xyz', ip: '192.168.**.**', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_282'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

Answer (score 0):

Partially this issue has been resolved, now I am able run Automation script via jenkins using Headless chrome. Actually headless chrome supports onwards selenium version 3.6 and I was using 3.4 so earlier even I was not able perform with headless browser.

But using headless chrome browser most of the my UI Automation test cases are getting FAIL.

Still I am facing issue to Launch UI chrome browser. Actually ChromeDriver is starting successfully but browser is not Launching so my test cases are getting ignored.

[image: Newly observed error]

Answer (score 0):

I found that I need to do **Xvfb** Setup- It helps to configure GUI on Linux.
sudo apt-get -y install xvfb
sudo chmod 777 /run/user/

After configuring it my issue has been resolved.